# chrome extension popup window resizability

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Just a simple question. My chrome extension is to open a popup window. How can I make this popup window not resizable?

The code:

```
<html>
    <script>

    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
        chrome.windows.create({'url':'popup.html', 'type': 'panel', 'height': 415, 'width': 670}, function(window) { });
    });

    </script>
</html>
```